# Changing XML structure in SOAP Handler

Tags: java, xml, soap, axis, jax-rpc

I use Axis 1.4 and I want to insert an additional level within in the XML of a SOAP body within the client. There is a server response, which I can get with a subclass of javax.xml.rpc.handler.GenericHandler in the client:

Now I try to recognize the right message type with

```
SOAPMessageContext smc = (SOAPMessageContext) context;
SOAPMessage message = smc.getMessage();
SOAPBody sb = message.getSOAPBody();

NodeList nl = sb.getElementsByTagName("projectDataReturn");
if (nl.getLength() == 0) {
    return true;  // wrong message
}

log.info("we have a projectDataReturn structure");

NodeList cl = sb.getElementsByTagName("centres");
if (cl.getLength() == 0) {
    return true;  // no centres
}

log.info("we have centres tags");
```

At this point I need a new tag, which holds all existing `<centres>` tags. The list of all `<centres>` tags I have stored in `cl` already, but how I can add new nodes to the `<projectDataReturn>` tag? And how I can move the existing `<centre>` tags to the new tag?. I have tried it with

```
Document doc = cl.item(0).getOwnerDocument();

Element array = doc.createElement("centres");
array.setAttribute("xmlns:ns5",  "http://beans.eo.xyz.de");
array.setAttribute("soapenc:arrayType", "ns5:CentreBean[" + cl.getLength() + "]");
array.setAttribute("xsi:type", "soapenc:Array");
array.setAttribute("xmlns:soapenc", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/");

nl.item(0).appendChild(array); 

// move existing <centre> tags here
return true;
```

But it produces a SOAPException

```
javax.xml.rpc.JAXRPCException: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Could not get document from SOAPEnvelope
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:

```
Document doc = cl.item(0).getOwnerDocument();

Element array = doc.createElementNS("", "centres");
array.setAttributeNS("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/", "soapenc:arrayType", "CentreBean[" + cl.getLength() + "]");
array.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:soapenc", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/");
array.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xsi/", "xsi:type", "soapenc:Array");
```

Now I clone the old `<centres>` nodes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cl.getLength(); i++) {
    array.appendChild(cl.item(i).cloneNode(true));
}
```

Now I insert the new node into the XML (in front of the old `<centres>` tags):

```
nl.item(0).insertBefore(array, cl.item(0));
```

And I remove the old nodes, which are on the wrong place:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cl.getLength(); i++) {
    nl.item(0).removeChild(cl.item(i));
}
```

If you register the handler code in the handler chain of your service stub on client side, it will be executed just before the XML deserialization of the server response:

```
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.rpc.handler.HandlerInfo;
import javax.xml.rpc.handler.HandlerRegistry;

// uses Axis1 generated client classes
MyService_Service serviceLocator = new MyService_ServiceLocator();

HandlerRegistry hr = serviceLocator.getHandlerRegistry();
List<HandlerInfo> handlerChain = hr.getHandlerChain((QName) serviceLocator.getPorts().next());

HandlerInfo hi = new HandlerInfo();
hi.setHandlerClass(MyXMLInjectionHandler.class);
handlerChain.add(hi);
```